# Delete List Item in MVC WebShop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, webshop

I am doing a webshop projet for my class but I am having one error in the delete, the exception happens in this line `if (cart[index].Amount == 1)`
it says *An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code*

```
private int isExisting(int id)
        {
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cart[i].Cl.Id == id)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(int idDelete)
        {
            int index = isExisting(idDelete);
            List<Item> cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];
            if (cart[index].Amount == 1) {
                cart.RemoveAt(index);
                Session["cart"] = cart;
            }else
            {
                cart[index].Amount--;
                Session["cart"] = cart;
            }

            return View("Order"); 

        }
```

Comment: `index` is likely to be some value bigger than the number of items in the list. Make sure that you are passing a zero-index based value, for ex: 0 for the first, 1 for the second and so on.

Comment: Add validation before "if (cart[index].Amount == 1)". might be you are getting index -1 or "cart" length is zero.